# Disparador o procedimiento almacenado after update

Tags: mysql

Verán, estoy tratando de automatizar unas operaciones en unas tablas. Tengo 2 tablas, Ordenes y Ordenes_Cancelados. Su estructura es la siguiente:

```
==Ordenes==

ID_ORDEN | ID_MESA | ESTADO | # PERSONAS | FECHA |



==Ordenes_Cancelados==

ID_CANCEL | ID_ORDEN | FECHA |
```

El campo ESTADO de la tabla Ordenes contendrá 'SERVIDO' o 'CANCELADO'. Lo que quiero hacer es que al alterar algún registro de esa tabla y setear ese campo con 'CANCELADO' llevar los datos requeridos de ese registro(ID_CANCEL,ID_ORDEN Y FECHA) a la tabla Ordenes_Cancelados, y enseguida eliminar ese registro de la tabla Ordenes.

Estuve viendo la manera de hacerlo con un trigger , pero no tengo claro como podría hacerlo así, si es que se puede, si algún entendido me tira un cable (links o alguna otra idea) le estaré muy agradecido.

PD: Estoy trabajando con MariaDB mediante PHPMyAdmin, aclaro esto pues no se si cambie mucho la sintaxis entre gestores de BD.

Answer (score 1):

Realmente no tiene mucha lógica la forma en que estás enfocando el problema... ¿actualizar un registro que en realidad debe ser borrado?

Estaríamos hablando de las siguientes acciones:

1. Que se indique por algún medio que el estado debe ser `CANCELADO`
2. Actualizar el estado del registro a `CANCELADO` (gastando tiempo y recursos para nada)
3. Informar a la otra tabla de que el registro se va a eliminar
4. y eventualmente insertar el registro en `Ordenes_Cancelados`
5. Borrar el registro en `Ordenes`

¿Cómo enlazar esas acciones *ilógicas*, más aún, en bases de datos como MySQL (y MariaDB en consecuencia) en las que no puedes modificar una tabla en uso desde un `TRIGGER`. O sea, el `TRIGGER` que escucharía las actualizaciones en `Ordenes` no podría al mismo tiempo borrar el registro, porque ya hay una acción (`UPDATE`) que se está operando sobre él.

Además, ¿cómo manejar errores, como que el `UPDATE` falle por algún motivo?

Lo correcto sería:

1. Cuando `Ordenes` reciba un estado `CANCELADO` actuar inmediatamente un `DELETE` sobre ese registro
2. Crear un `TRIGGER` para `Ordenes` que inserte los datos del registro que se ha borrado en `Ordenes_Cancelados`

El `TRIGGER` sería:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER onCancelledOrder
AFTER DELETE
    ON Ordenes 
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Ordenes_Cancelados 
            (
                ID_ORDEN,
                FECHA
             ) VALUES (
                 OLD.ID_ORDEN,
                 OLD.FECHA
             );
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Tendrías el problema resuelto con ese `TRIGGER` e incorporando en la **lógica del programa** un código que ejecute una sentencia parecida a esta cuando el valor destinado al estado sea igual a `CANCELADO`:

```
-- Cuando por algún medio el valor de ESTADO deba pasar a CANCELADO
DELETE FROM Ordenes WHERE ID_ORDEN=2;
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

---

#### Demostración

Aquí puedes ver una <kbd>[**DEMOSTRACIÓN EN LÍNEA**](https://rextester.com/MZG36598)</kbd> del código.